# Fases del display en iOs(Constraints)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Quería saber si alguien puede explicarme los métodos de `UIView` acerca de como se actualizan los constraints, de la fase de `layout` de las `UIView`, y la sobre el `display`.

Mi duda viene sobre en que orden y como funcionan los métodos
`updateViewConstraints()`, `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()`, `updateConstraints()`, `layoutIfNeeded()`, `setNeedsLayout()`,`setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`, los cuales están relacionados.

Imagen de la cual vino la duda
[image: Imagen de la cual vino la duda]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí van unos ejemplos de cómo se usan los métodos:

1. `updateConstraints()`

   Hacer override de este método cuando quieres que un `UIView` subclass se encarga de especificar constraints a sus subviews.

   ```
   class AView: UIView {
       var yaAgregoConstraints = false
       override func updateConstraints() {
           print(#function)
           if yaAgregoConstraints == false {
               yaAgregoConstraints = true
               addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 60))
               addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 60))
           }
           super.updateConstraints()
       }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let aView = AView()
       aView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
       aView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       view.addSubview(aView)
   }
   ```
2. `setNeedsLayout()` y `layoutIfNeeded()`

   Continuando el ejemplo anterior, digamos que queremos saber el
   tamaño de la vista `aView` después de crearla. Agregamos esto al
   final de `viewDidLoad()`:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       ...

       print(aView.frame)
   }
   ```

   Imprime:

   ```
   (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)  // esto es incorrecto!
   updateConstraints()   // lo que hace print(#function)
   ```

   Imprime un tamaño de cero porque después de crear la vista `aView`, tiene constraints, pero todavía no han sido calculados para que `aView` tenga un tamaño (un layout pass, que da tamaño a `aView`, ocurre un poco más tarde). Si ya queremos que se calcule su tamaño, invocamos estos métodos antes de pedir el tamaño a `aView`:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       ...

       aView.setNeedsLayout()
       aView.layoutIfNeeded()
       print(aView.frame) 
   }
   ```

   Imprime:

   ```
   updateConstraints()    // ahora updateConstraints se ejecuta primero
   (0.0, 0.0, 60.0, 60.0)  // y el tamaño es correcto
   ```
3. `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` y `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()`

   El sistema llama al método `updateConstraints()` en cada layout-pass (cada cierta cantidad de milli-segundos). Llama a la implementación por defecto de `updateConstraints()` o a la implementación que especificamos. Para cortar esta espera del layout-pass y hacer que el sistema ya llame a `updateConstraints()`, invocar a los métodos así:

   ```
   setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
   updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
   ```
4. `updateViewConstraints()`

   `updateViewConstraints()` [es equivalente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626094/1305067) a `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`, pero es un método de `UIViewController`, no de `UIView`, cómo los métodos anteriores.

Más información (en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609206/setneedslayout-vs-setneedsupdateconstraints-and-layoutifneeded-vs-updateconstra